# form framework in news detail view

Tags: typo3

I tried to implement a form with form framework in the news detail view. The basic way is explained here:
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/10.4/en-us/I/Concepts/FrontendRendering/Index.html#render-within-your-own-extbase-extension

Viewhelper:

```
<formvh:render persistenceIdentifier="EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Forms/myforms.form.yaml"/>
```

Form definition:

```
renderingOptions:
  controllerAction: detailAction
  addQueryString: true
  submitButtonLabel: Absenden
  fluidAdditionalAttributes:
  class: ''
identifier: myForm
label: 'myLabel'
type: Form
prototypeName: myPrototype
```

The form is displayed. When I submit the form the news detail view is shown again including the form, but it's empty. The form is not processed. Something is missing, but I cannot find it in the manual.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of experimenting i was able to solve the problem. It ist simply a matter of caching ...

Georg has implemented in news a special caching engine which ignores the config.no_cache = 1 definition in setup. So the detail view of news is always cached even when the whole installation ist set to config.no_cache = 1. So this combination seems to work:

Viewhelper in Detail.html:

```
<formvh:render persistenceIdentifier="EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Forms/myforms.form.yaml"/>
```

And this definitions in the yaml file of the form:

```
renderingOptions:
  controllerAction: detail
  addQueryString: true
  submitButtonLabel: Absenden
  additionalParams: 
    no_cache: 1
identifier: myForm
label: 'myLabel'
type: Form
prototypeName: myPrototype
```

This renders the whole page without cache which is not optimal. It would be better when only the news entry is rendered without cache. and there is the problem, that in many installations the parameter 'disableNoCacheParameter' is set in the localconfiguration file which disallowes no_cache=1 in urls.

So i looked for an other - better - possibility to work around this problem.

First make a new fluid template anywhere in your resources folder with the modified viewhelper from above:

```
<formvh:render persistenceIdentifier="{settings.persistenceIdentifier}"/>
```

Then write a typoscript like this:

```
lib.embeddedForm = COA_INT
lib.embeddedForm {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Forms/myForm.html
        settings {
            EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Forms/myforms.form.yaml
        }
        extbase {
            pluginName = Formframework
            controllerExtensionName = Form
            controllerName = FormFrontend
            controllerActionName = perform
        }
    }
}
```

And final you can embed the form with

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.embeddedForm" />
```

as COA_INT in the news template. This disables the caching of the form.

Perhaps it helps ...

Comment: Thanks @lisardo for your solution. There is one typo in your TypoScript lib. It must be like this (snippet):


`settings.persistenceIdentifier = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Forms/myforms.form.yaml`

The key `persistenceIdentifier` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the important part is written in the note below the linked paragraph:

> In general, you can override each and every form definition with the help of TypoScript (see ‘TypoScript overrides’). This feature is not supported when you are rendering forms via the RenderViewHelper.
>
> Luckily, there is a solution for your problem: use the ‘overrideConfiguration’ parameter instead. This way, you can override the form definition within your template. Provide an according array as shown in the example below.
>
> ```
> <formvh:render persistenceIdentifier="EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Forms/MyForm.yaml" overrideConfiguration="{renderables: {0: {renderables: {0: {label: 'My shiny new label'}}}}}"/>
> ```

That means you can check for post-variables by TypoScript conditions and adjust the controllerAction (and view) accordingly. The show / detail action is not processing the form usually, so it's logical that another action has to be assigned. I'm not sure in the moment if it does matter if double opt-in or a confirmation page shall be shown, that might depend on the form-extension.

Comment: I dont think that is the problem here. I can define the controller action and the handling of querystring directly in the yaml of the form. No need for the overrideConfiguration. The problem is: when i use detailAction the news is shown and the form not processed. If i use perform i get an exception because news dont have this controller. I dont think that it is possible to implement form in an extension as it is described in the manual. There has to be something missing ...